# javascript regex : only english letters allowed

Tags: javascript, regex

Quick question: I need to allow an input to only accept letters, from a to z and from A to Z, but can't find any expression for that. I want to use the javascript test() method.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

```js
let res = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test('sfjd');
console.log(res);
```

Note: If you have any punctuation marks or anything, those are all invalid too. Dashes and underscores are invalid. `\w` covers a-zA-Z and some other word characters. It all depends on what you need specifically.

Comment: do you know if there is much of a difference between regex.test(string) and string.match(regex)?

Comment: hmm it seems I was missing only the start and end tags, thanks!

Comment: what about other languages' letters?

Comment: how can you allow punctuation like all letters but also you might have united-states as allowable?

Comment: @WeDoTDD Like this: `^[a-zA-Z]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)*$`. The regular expression accepts at least one English letter, and then naught or more of one dash and at least one letter. That allows `a`,  `a-a`, `a-a-a`, and so on (using `a` to stand for at least one capital or lower-case letter). You can change the asterisk (**`*`**) to a question mark (**`?`**) if you want to allow at most one dash (e.g. only `a` or `a-a`).

Answer (score 16):

Another option is to use the [case-insensitive flag i](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), then there's no need for the extra character range A-Z.

```
var reg = /^[a-z]+$/i;
console.log( reg.test("somethingELSE") ); //true
console.log( "somethingELSE".match(reg)[0] ); //"somethingELSE"
```

Here's a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/shawn1/ebuno94c/) on how this regex works with test() and match().

Comment: Just to clarify, will this expression return null when there is some other, say, '&' character is present? IF there are only English letters, then it will return the input itself?

Comment: @MadPhysicist TLDR; Yes.  Explanation: Using `string.match(regex)` will return null if there are no matches otherwise it returns an array of matched strings.  Since this regex is matching everything from the start of the string (`^`) to the end of the string (`$`), a match() here will return the whole string or null.  See my [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/shawn1/ebuno94c/) above for uses of `regex.test(string)` or `string.match(regex)`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist clarification:  match() here actually returns an array with the whole string at the zero index.

Answer (score 5):

The answer that accepts empty string:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test('something')
```

the `*` means 0 or more occurrences of the preceding item.