# Javascript regex: test people's name

Tags: javascript, regex

From this questions : [javascript regex : only english letters allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073176/javascript-regex-only-letters-allowed)

How can I make that expression test for people's name? Currently it doesn't allow spaces between names at all. I need to be able to match something like **John Doe**

Cheers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```js
let result = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test( 'John Doe');
console.log(result);
```

Throw any symbols you need in the character class. This is *why* I said be *specific* about *exactly* what you want to validate. This regex will not account for accented characters, if you care about that you'd most likely better go with unicode matching.

Comment: and can I do it with javascript? Or will it need to be done server-side?

Comment: can someone provide an example?

Comment: @Yoda: You can do it on the client: var UsersName="!John Doe";
 
 if (/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(UsersName)) {
  alert('Valid name');
 } else {
  alert('Invalid name');
 }

This won't come out nice in a comment, but it's a working example.

Comment: that's just the same as @meder answer

Comment: @yoda - what did you need an example of? server-side? im confused.

Comment: Never do exclusively client side validation. I can disable javascript or hit your server from a custom crafted form. You don't want me saying my name is `' UNION ALL SELECT user,pass FROM mysql.users`

Comment: I'm aware of that, and I always do server-side validation .. I just want to do it client-side so that the users don't have to spend unecessary time fulling forms

Comment: This doesn't account for dashes ("-")

Comment: This passes `/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test('  ')`

Comment: This is not good because it passes first white space character

Comment: If you are expecting international names, remember that in some countries names have accents, like mine for example Ângelo. This regex doesn't validate accents.

Comment: Regex not work properly in name fields . it gives "true" in following cases also ->
/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test( '  John Doe')  OR  /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test( '  John D oe') OR /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test( '  John D oe   ')

Comment: I will share few names with you, you will see the issue.
Frederick adam donny, IV
John Kipng'etich Kibowen

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
/^(([A-Za-z]+[\-\']?)*([A-Za-z]+)?\s)+([A-Za-z]+[\-\']?)*([A-Za-z]+)?$/
```

It expects optionally [at least 1 alphabetical character followed by a ' or -] an indefinite number of times.  There must be at least one alphabetical character before a required space to ensure we are getting at least the first and last name.  This entire pattern is grouped to accept indefinite repetition (for people who like to use all their names, such as John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt), but must appear at least once, by means of the + sign right in the middle.  Finally, the last name is treated the same way as the other names, but no trailing space is allowed.  (Unfortunately this means we are violating DRY a little bit.)

Here is the outcome on several possible pieces of input:

```
"Jon Doe": true
"Jonathan Taylor Thomas": true
"Julia Louis-Dreyfus": true
"Jean-Paul Sartre": true
"Pat O'Brien": true
"Þór Eldon": false
"Marcus Wells-O'Shaugnessy": true
"Stephen Wells-O'Shaugnessy Marcus": true
"This-Is-A-Crazy-Name Jones": true
"---- --------": false
"'''' ''''''''": false
"'-'- -'-'-'-'": false
"a-'- b'-'-'-'": false
"'-'c -'-'-'-d": false
"e-'f g'-'-'-h": false
"'ij- -klmnop'": false
```

Note it still doesn't handle Unicode characters, but it could possibly be expanded to include those if needed.

Comment: Folks, all the test cases are listed above.  If you find it doesn't work with something, then make it yourself and then submit it as an answer.  Be a part of the solution, not the precipitate. ;)

Answer (score 16):

```
^\s*([A-Za-z]{1,}([\.,] |[-']| ))+[A-Za-z]+\.?\s*$
```

Similar as @Stephen_Wylie's solution, but shorter (better?).

Comment: Great answer! Thank You! I think Your regex is the only one that **matches all** of the following: `"Kiersten F. Latham", "Pat O'Brien", "Marcus Wells-O'Shaugnessy", "Stephen Wells-O'Shaugnessy Marcus", "This-Is-A-Crazy-Name Jones"`

Comment: **Note:** If You need to match one-word names, just add a `?` after `([.,] |[-']| )`, or leave the `?` out and add `|\w+` at the end of the whole expression.

Comment: can you explain the regex? what are the rules to display to the user? (for example, one letter, allow `-` ...)

Answer (score 7):

FWIW, I wrote this regex for cleaning up names:

```js
let name = "John Doe";
let result = name.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_'-]/gi, '');
console.log(result);
```

This will let names like O'Brien, Smith, Smith-O'Brian pass through, but will prevent "names" like Engle;drop user; from being passed through.  Anyway, it's four years after the fact, but hopefully my answer is of some use.

Comment: Thanks, it will be usefull :)

Answer (score 2):

The below code works for my case:

```
const isControlValid = control.value.match(/^[\x41-\x5A\x61-\x7A\xAA\xB5\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u0527\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5\u06E6\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u07F4\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0\u08A2-\u08AC\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0977\u0979-\u097F\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C33\u0C35-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58\u0C59\u0C60\u0C61\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D60\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F4\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191C\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19C1-\u19C7\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE\u1BAF\u1BBA-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C7D\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FCC\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA697\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA78E\uA790-\uA793\uA7A0-\uA7AA\uA7F8-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA80-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uABC0-\uABE2\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC,'-.\s]+$/g);
const hasErrorCombinations = control.value.match(/(([^\x00-\x7F]+|[\w]+)?[.|\-|'|.|\s]{2,}([^\x00-\x7F]+|[\w]+)?)+|([^\x00-\x7F]+|[\w]+)?[.|\-|\s]{1}$|^[.|\-|\s]{1}([^\x00-\x7F]+|[\w]+)?$/g);
const hasAdditionalSymbolsCheckErrors = control.value.match(/[()+*]+/g);

return isControlValid && !hasErrorCombinations && !hasAdditionalSymbolsCheckErrors;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a space

```
^[\w ]+$
```

Nor sure if it's your need.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a short approach

```
([A-Za-z]+(['|\-|\s]?[A-Za-z]+)*)+
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

In name, you can use a dash, space, and single quote.

`^[ a-zA-Z\-\']+$`

and also for special symbols

`` /^[ a-zA-ZàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ'`'\-]+$/ ``