# SQL Safety with Whitelisting

Tags: javascript, sql, security, sql-injection

On my app's registration page, there is a field for the user's name. I would like to prevent SQL injection attacks while allowing complex names like `Aldéric D'Aurve-Sanct`, which contain single quotes used as apostrophes.

If I whitelist the name using a [regex string like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29037473/1484617), can I then use double quotes (which are not allowed in the name) to fully escape the string? In other words, is it safe to use a string containing single quotes, but not other control characters, when surrounded by double quotes? Are there any vulnerabilities which such simple solution might introduce?

*Note: I don't want to use prepared statements in this instance.*

Comment: Why don't you *want* to use prepared statements in this instance?

Comment: Simply properly escape the offending characters.

Comment: Using prepared statements would involve redoing a lot of code, so I'm looking for an easier way that's still fairly secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really can't use prepared statements, never escape yourself, there is functions to do it if you ever need it.

For example, if you use php PDO, use PDO::quote : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

But, use prepared statements if possible :

- No need to blacklist
- No need to escape
- No risk of injection
- Everything is allowed