# Javascript .length property and string/numeric validation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate a form, specifically right now a "city" text box field. If the city is empty or less than 3 characters, then an alert comes up. Also not allowing numbers to show up in string text boxes, and no strings in number fields(age)..
I tried: (no luck)

```
if(firstName.value="" || isNaN(firstName)
{
    errorMessage = "Enter valid first name. No numbers."
}
```

This is what I have, but city less than 3 char. doesn't work? along with checking if input is numeric or string.

```
var errorMessage = "";

    if(firstName.value == "")
    {
        errorMessage = "Enter a valid first name.\n";
    } 

if(lastName.value == "")
{
    errorMessage = errorMessage + "Enter a valid last name.\n";
    }
    if(age.value =="" || age.value <= 0)
    {
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "Enter a valid age. No strings\n";
    }

    if(city.value == "" || city.length < 3)
    {
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "Enter a valid city, more than 3 char.";
    }



    //displays error messages
    if(firstName.value=="" || lastName.value == "" || age.value=="" || age.value <=0 || city.value=="" || city.length <3)
    {
        alert(errorMessage);

    }

    else{
        alert("success");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you getting firstName, GetElementBy...?

Comment: how are you getting the value of city

Comment: Make sure `city` is defined and contains the string.

Comment: Can you post your form here or JSBIN

Comment: I assume `if(firstName.value=""` is a typo? (assignment as opposed to equality testing)

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone, and ya I'm using getElementById for all the variables. 
Any advice on how to allow only string in the text fields. Would isNaN work? Couldn't get it to work with isNaN how I was doing it

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with your structure, it should probably be

```
city.value == "" || city.value.length < 3
```

To screen this by only letters, you could include a regex<sup>1</sup> statement

```
city.value == "" || city.value.length < 3 || /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(city.value)
```

<sub>1. regex from answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3073186/1026459</sub>

Comment: Thank you Travis! it worked, now I know I need .value in there too! Appreciate the help. Any advice on allowing only string? Tried isNaN several times, but it wouldn't work. Any kind of advice would be appreciated, Thanks again

Comment: Beauty, thanks again. I looked into my power points next week and were studying regular expressions. Is that kind of what that is then? 
And I could use the same for numbers, but instead of [a-zA-Z]..replace it with say [1-100].

Comment: @Atlas182 - Yup, that is regex (a regular expression). For numbers you would use `/^[0-9]+$/`,

Comment: Sorry one last thing Travis, I can add that to the firstName, lastName fields too? like,,

if(lastName.value == "" || /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(lastName.value))
  {
   errorMessage = errorMessage + "Enter a valid last name.\n";
  }

Comment: Yup, you can. It just produces a true or false value based on the regular expression evaluating the test string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46374/discussion-between-atlas182-and-travis-j)