# Alpha-only character validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on this code in which it checks validation on numeric characters. In the same way, I want validation on alpha-only characters. I have tried many symbols but failed to succeed.

```
if (/\D/.test(x))
{
  alert("Please only enter numeric characters  (Allowed input:0-9)")
  return false;
}
```

What changes are required in this code for alpha-only validation.

Comment: $10 says that the one thing you didn't try was a google search

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript regex : only letters allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073176/javascript-regex-only-letters-allowed)

Comment: i have tried this in if condition (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)

Answer (score 0):

**Using .test()**

If you want to keep with the .test() method, I believe that the below would work for you.

Identify if the input is numeric.

```
if (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(x))
{
  alert("Please only enter numeric characters  (Allowed input:0-9)")
  return false;
}
```

Identify if the input contains a-z/A-Z

```
if (!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(x))
{
    alert("Please only enter letters (Allowed input: a-z, A-Z)")
  return false;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3AnQr/)

**Not Using .test()**

You can also set up functions that look for the value during the onkeypress event

Allow only numerical characters to be entered in select fields || onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;

    if(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){return false;}
    return true;
}
```

Allow only alpha characters to be entered in select fields || onkeypress="return isAlphaKey(event)"

```
function isAlphaKey(evt) 
{
    evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
    var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode :((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));

    if(charCode > 32 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)){return false;}
    return true;
}
```